# Vaadin14 fullcalendar applyChangesOnEntry return wrong resource

Tags: fullcalendar, vaadin, vaadin14

I'm having some problem with fullcalendar and I can't figure out how to solve the problem. My code was previously working on vaadin 13 with fullcalendar 1.9.2.

**My code:**

```
calendar.addEntryDroppedListener((EntryDroppedEvent e) -> {
ExtendedResourceEntry entry = (ExtendedResourceEntry) e.applyChangesOnEntry();
ScheduleEvent event = entry.getEvent();
event.setEventStart(entry.getStart().toLocalDate());
event.setEventEnd(entry.getEnd().toLocalDate());
for (ScheduleResource scheduleResource : resourceMap.keySet()) {
    final Resource r = resourceMap.get(scheduleResource);
    if (r.equals(entry.getResource().get())) {
        //Do my stuff
    }
}
```

});

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.vaadin.stefan</groupId>
    <artifactId>fullcalendar2-scheduler</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.vaadin.stefan</groupId>
    <artifactId>fullcalendar2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<repository>
   <id>vaadin-addons</id>
   <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
</repository>
```

**This is how the code was working with Vaadin 13:**

1. Drag the event from "Resource 1"
2. Drop the event on "Resource 2"
3. Display popup with three option (Copy, Move, Abort) (The user select one)
4. Copy or Move the dragged (Resource 1) event to the selected (Resource 2) resource (row)

**This is how the code is working now with Vaadin 14:**

1. Drag the event from "Resource 1"
2. Drop the event on "Resource 2"
3. Display popup with three option (Copy, Move, Abort) (The user select one)
4. Copy or Move the dragged (Resource 1) event to the the same resource, so it duplicate the event on the same resource (row)

Here the problem is that applyChangesOnEntry does not apply the right resource. How do I get the right resource?

Comment: Hi Carlo. What is your question? What do you expect from an answer?

Comment: @kscherrer Edit made, the question is: How do I get the right resource? Consider that nothing in my code is changed, so it must work as previously. I don't know if something is change in the APIs, or if I'm missing a new flag that enable the drag&drop between different rows

Comment: Which add-on do you use? I can see that the author of the [Full Calendar](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/full-calendar-web-component) add-on has made a separate add-on for Vaadin 14 npm mode [here](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/full-calendar-4-web-component). Are you maybe using the first one which is not compatible with V14 npm mode?

Comment: @kscherrer I'm using [the second one](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/full-calendar-4-web-component/2.0.0#), check my pom.xml

Comment: why are you using such an ancient version of fullCalendar? And, dragging and dropping events between resources can be enabled automatically using built-in functionality of fullCalendar, certainly from version 2 onwards, but it's probably better in the newest version. And there are callbacks available where you can inject things into the process, such as having a popup appear. I'm not sure you need lots of your own code to do this. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-dragging-resizing

Comment: @ADyson you are mistaking the js library version with the java (vaadin) component version. I can see in the [git repo](https://github.com/stefanuebe/vaadin_fullcalendar/) of said vaadin component (version 2.0.0) that the used js library version is v4.3.1

Comment: I can see in the github repo there is already an [open issue about exactly this](https://github.com/stefanuebe/vaadin_fullcalendar/issues/36). Also, I saw [a comment](https://github.com/stefanuebe/vaadin_fullcalendar/issues/35) from the author stating they are not able to work on this until at least april this year.

Comment: @kscherrer thanks that's helpful. OP mentioned fullCalendar 1.9.2 in the post, but I guess, on re-reading, that this was an old version and now they have upgraded. Nonetheless, the point still stands that dragging/dropping is supported directly by fullCalendar, and it's unclear why other JS code would be required to carry it out.

Comment: @kscherrer I saw the issues and comments on GitHub, that is why I have posted the question here. The author is unable to work on this for a long reading the comment, but I can't wait too much, so if we are able to find the solution well, we share it with the community and help someone else, if not I must solve it changing the logic and replacing this event with something else..

Comment: @ADyson I'm not understanding what are you suggesting to do, remove my custom code in this event and open the popup with the drag&drop supported by fullcalendar?

Comment: @CarloZanocco for clarity, since I'm familiar with fullCalendar only, and not the vaaddin platform, I'm guessing the code you've posted above is server-side Java, rather than JavaScript? The syntax doesn't look right for JavaScript. If so then, to my mind, I can't think of a reason really why you'd need to do anything on the server-side to deal with a simple drag and drop operation.

Comment: Everything, including the popup behaviour, could be implemented more efficiently using JavaScript. I think you'd only need to talk to the server once you've confirmed that an event's data has changed, and the changed data needs saving to the database. That's my view on it, anyhow.

Comment: @ADyson there are several reason for that, I can't explain it now because isn't required to solve the problem, I will consider it as solution if I can't solve the problem with this code.

Comment: From the code you've shown, it all uses data coming from the calendar which appears to be used purely to manipulate the user interface. So unless you haven't shown part of it, I can't see anything which couldn't be replaced by client-side code without having any impact. If any other interaction with server data _is_ required during the drag process, it could potentially be done via AJAX, I would expect. So fine you can decide not to give details for your reasons, but that will make it harder for me to form an accurate opinion on what your best option is.

Comment: @ADyson Check the full code

Comment: Hm ok. That all still looks like user-interface code. So should be replaceable with client-side functionality, would likely be a better user experience. The only bits I can see that aren't are the calls to save the event, but that's all in response to specific user actions as far as I can see, so the same triggers could be implemented client-side, and then just the data itself sent to the server to be stored. Just my opinion, and of course it's some work, but it would get round your bug I think, and probably improve the user experience as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem reading the pull request on github. It is accessible [here](https://github.com/stefanuebe/vaadin_fullcalendar/pull/38).
This user made the working code, maybe the developer will merge it in future